# Why is the need and the value of the bias resistor is dependent to the source output resistance?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

Regarding [this information](https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=AU&lc=eng&ckey=1465069&nid=-34677.536908562.00&id=1465069),

[image]

regarding the bias resistor the page says:

> The resistor value is equivalent to about 100 times the source
>   impedance. If the source impedance is less than 100 Ω, you can connect
>   the negative polarity of the signal directly to AI_GND, as well as the
>   negative input of the Instrumentation Amplifier.

**1-)** Why a bias resistor needed if the source impedance is less than 100 Ω and otherwise not?

**2-)** What is so special for the source impedance being about 100 Ω in this context? It is not product specific since the same 100 Ω recommendation can be found in another source like [this one](http://www.etechnoshop.com/adlink/dl/manual/e/DAQ-2213+2214_Manual_6.pdf) at page 26 under Floating source and differential input.

Comment: With 100 ohm or less source impedance the instrumentation amp sees very little difference across its inputs relative to ground. With a large impedance the source must "float" with just a static reference to ground, hence a high value resistor. As a general rule the lower the source impedance the better the signal quality if it has to travel many yards/meters to the amp.

Comment: I have both single ended and diff ended transducers. What do you think about this wiring: What do you think about this wiring: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUAsh.png ?

Comment: That wiring diagram (.png) is correct.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I wasn't sure about 10k resistors use. Some articles dont mention it some do. And also in that png I drew the AIGND connects to the earth at the end which I wasn't sure it needed to be. What also worries me if the transducers I will use have source impedances and unbalance can cause magnetic pick up. See my second question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351483/a-question-about-the-use-of-static-reference-resistor-and-balancing-a-floating-s

Answer (score 1):

From this page: http://www.beam.org.uk/opensource/pci-6143/docsource/S_Series_Help.chm/Differential_Connections_for_Nonreferenced_or_Floating_Signal_Sources.html

> **DC-Coupled, Low Source Impedance**
>
> You must reference the source to AI GND. The easiest way to make this
>   reference is to connect the positive side of the signal to the
>   positive input of the instrumentation amplifier and connect the
>   negative side of the signal to AI GND as well as to the negative input
>   of the instrumentation amplifier, without using resistors. This
>   connection works well for DC-coupled sources with low source impedance
>   (less than 100 Ω).
>
> **DC-Coupled, High Source Impedance**
>
> For larger source impedances, this connection leaves the DIFF signal
>   path significantly off balance. Noise that couples electrostatically
>   onto the positive line does not couple onto the negative line because
>   it is connected to ground. Hence, this noise appears as a DIFF-mode
>   signal instead of a common-mode signal, and the instrumentation
>   amplifier does not reject it. In this case, instead of directly
>   connecting the negative line to AI GND, connect the negative line to
>   AI GND through a resistor that is about 100 times the equivalent
>   source impedance. The resistor puts the signal path nearly in balance,
>   so that about the same amount of noise couples onto both connections,
>   yielding better rejection of electrostatically coupled noise. This
>   configuration does not load down the source (other than the very high
>   input impedance of the instrumentation amplifier).

100Ω seems to be fairly arbitrary crossover between 'low' and 'high' source impedance.

Comment: Please also see this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350799/confusion-with-different-recommendations-about-wiring-floating-single-ended-outp